# Showing User Details and Shipping Address on account dashboard

Tags: woocommerce, dashboard, account

I would like to be able to show more user details than I'm able to figure out in the woocommerce account dashboard. Details being name and email fields.

Also would like to add shipping details aswell?

[image: woocommerce account dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

My details answer

```
 <?php
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        /**
         * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
         *     return;
         */
        echo 'Email:' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
        echo 'First Name:' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
        echo 'Last Name:' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    ?>
```

Address add to functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account__shipping_dashboard', 'woocommerce_account_edit_address' );
```

Add to dashboard to show address

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_account__shipping_dashboard' ); ?>
```